# Can an Office Add-in run without Edge/IE installed?

Tags: webview, office-js, microsoft-edge, office-addins, webview2

We have a client that wants to run our Excel Add-in (web-based Office Add-in written with office-js), however, they don't have Edge or IE installed.
They are running Version 2008 (Build 13127.21766) of Excel, which according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins) from Microsoft uses the EdgeHTML WebView (Edge Legacy)

[image]

I know with the WebView2 runtimes you can install the runtime separately since Windows 8.1 and 10 didn't come with that runtime.
Can the same process be followed for the EdgeHTML WebView (Edge Legacy), as in can we install an EdgeHTML WebView runtime while not having Edge installed?
If so can someone point me in the right direction on where to get this runtime from?

Comment: I don't understand, in 2008 the EdgeHTML was not released at all. Besides, computers without Edge Chromium does have IE installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to get the EdgeHTML webview installed is to install Edge.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the client is on a Windows version? According to my knowledge, Excel 2008 which belongs to Office 2008 is only for Mac. You can refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/microsoft-office-2008-for-mac) and [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_2008_for_Mac).

According to [the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins) you mentioned, they can use Safari for Office Add-ins on Mac.

[image]

Comment: It's not Office 2008 it's version 2008.